# Аллокаторы, использование метода construct()

Tags: c++, память, vector, std

Переписываю стандартный контейнер `std::vector` на C++98 с поддержкой `std::allocator`'а

Мы можем выделять память при помощи `_alloc.allocate()`, а зачем дальше инициализировать память с помощью `_alloc.construct()`, нужно ли это делать в случае с вектором, ведь по сути это хранилище ссылок?

Без вызова `construct()` или с ним, все работает, и примитивы, и пользовательские типы данных , и объекты сохраняются и ими можно пользоваться.

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ :**
Немного поэкспериментировал, подскажите почему данный случай отрабатывает нормально:

```
class User
{
public:
    int id;
    User(int id) : id(id) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::allocator<User> _allocator;
    User *objects = _allocator.allocate(3);

    User obj1(1);
    User obj2(2);
    User obj3(3);

    objects[0] = obj1;
    objects[1] = obj2;
    objects[2] = obj3;

    _allocator.deallocate(objects, 3);
}
```

А этот кейс ругается на невалидную работу с памятью `uninitialised value` внутри `objects`:

```
int main()
{
    std::allocator<std::string> _allocator;
    std::string *objects = _allocator.allocate(3);

    std::string obj1("1");
    std::string obj2("2");
    std::string obj3("3");

    objects[0] = obj1;
    objects[1] = obj2;
    objects[2] = obj3;

    _allocator.deallocate(objects, 3);
}
```

Comment: Не помешает небольшой пример кода, где вы выделяете память для нескольких объектов типа `std::string`, а затем пользуетесь ими.

Comment: добавил, действительно, с std::string работает не так как я ожидал

Comment: `std::string` хранит указатель на динамическую память. Соответственно при присвоении `objects[0] = obj1` происходит не просто побайтовое копирование содержимого одного `std::string` в другой, а сперва читаются члены-данные `objects[0]`, чтобы принять решение как поступить с имеющейся в распоряжении  `objects[0]` памятью. А так как функция `construct` не вызывалась, то объект  `objects[0]` не инициализирован, т.е. происходит чтение неинициализированной памяти. Что вы и наблюдаете. Вот почему необходимо вызывать функцию `construct`.

Answer (score 1):

Верно_ `allocate` выделяет **сырую** память(там нет объектов) для количества элементов, указанных в ее аргументе. Но не забывайте, что этот аргумент зависит от  реализации вектора.
Стандартный вектор ведь  просит своему распределителю выделять память побольше, чем требуется для размещения элементов(это есть `capacity` вектора), но конструировать конкретное количество объектов_элементов вектора.

Например для 17 элементов, `allocate` может выделить память, например, под 24 элемента. Это означает, что данная функция_член вектора  вызывает `_alloc.allocate(24)`, а потом туда вставляет объекты вызовом `_alloc.construct(адрес и значения для конструирования объекта)`.

Реализация может быть разная, но `construct(T* p, Type arg)` примерно может делать, грубо говоря, следующее:

```
new(p)T(arg) //поместить T(arg) по адресу p
```

Если вы реализуете распределитель и стратегию вектора по другому, то может ваш  _alloc.allocate() выделит память под массив конкретных объектов, тогда да _ он заодно выполняет и конструирование, и метод construct не нужен